# Deprecate currency symbol from product price

Tags: php, regex, oscommerce

I am working on one of the ecommerce project in OScommerce and I have to implement google tracking in it, Google doesn't allows product price with currency symbol as a parameter in it's method . but on my payment success page I got product price with the currency symbol.
So, is there any way through which we extract numeric value from product price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$price_no_curr = preg_replace ( '#\D*?(\d+(\.\d+)?)\D*#', '$1', $price);
```

Comment: An explanation of how it works would make this answer better. This type of answer tends to fosters copy and paste coders.